# What happens behind the scenes with Xcode storyboards?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

What happens behind the scenes with Xcode storyboards?
Does building elements of a storyboard actually construct the code in .swift files, or the visual representation completely replaces code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the views that you drag onto and the constraints that you set up on the storyboard **get transcribed to XML: eXtensible Markup Language**, and will act as instructions to set up instances

> Extensible Markup Language is a markup language that defines a set of
>   rules for encoding documents in a format that is both human-readable
>   and machine-readable.

You might have noticed this already when you commit/face conflicts on your `.storyboard` files. You can have a look yourself by right-clicking a `.storyboard` file -> Open as -> Source Code

Answer (score 0):

The storyboard just describes instances, in text. Think of it as instructions for configuring instances.  When a nib is loaded (a view controller or its main view), those instructions are obeyed and real configured instances come into existence.

Storyboard: “Make a button at 50,75 with title OK.”

The runtime, when the nib loads: “Yes, master.”